# subclass's sharedClient Method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, singleton, superclass

In the superClass,i defined a method called "sharedClient"

```
+ (id)sharedClient
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc]init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

at this method i want to dispatch the object once .then i defined two subclasses of the superClass。class A,and class B.

i hope that after i've called the method sharedClient of A, there's a sharedClient of A, and I"ve called the sharedClient of B, there's an object of B.but it seems that if A and B called the method both, there always be one object of the previously called class。

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_once` does what it's name implies, so there will be only one alloc, and only one assignment to instance.  That will be an instance of whichever class is first called.

If you really want a singleton, then you probably don't want three classes.  Maybe you want a single instance of each?  Then each file would have a static instance variable and each class would have it's own implementation of sharedClient.